# Boost Intrusive Hooks

Tags: c++, boost, hook

Can anyone explain ***boost intrusive hooks*** concept? i don't understand reading the documentation
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/intrusive.html

Comment: Please do not downvote new users, comment the question or edit to improve it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost.intrusive forces you to provide information along the objects you want to store in an intrusive container.

Hooks are the way to provide the required information to the associated intrusive container. To do so, the class defining the objects you want to store can either inherit from the hook or own it as a member.

As long as the intrusive container needs to be fully known at compile time, hooks are parameterized using templates, which leads to a syntax where the option is a template class and the associated value is its parameter.

For instance, you can define the link mode by specifying the `link_mode` parameter in the template parameters list and set its value:

```
boost::intrusive::list< MyClass, boost::intrusive::link_mode< boost::intrusive::safe_link > > l;
```

Last but not least, if your hook contains non-default values, you will have to pass it as a template parameter to the intrusive container class you use.

Considering intrusive list for example, this means replacing

```
boost::intrusive::list<MyClass> l;
```

by

```
boost::intrusive::list<MyClass, MyHook> l;
```

Comment: Another way to think about hooks is as link-nodes, while it may be an over simplification they contain the "bext" and "prev" pointers for a double-linked-list, your object may have one or more of these nodes, each representing membership in different containers.  When its time to remove your object you can remove it from all containers in O(1)

Comment: Can you explain how a normal_link differs from safe_link and auto-unlink hooks? Is it that normal_link hook is just a mere hook without those functionalities offered by other hooks? Or it does something on its own?